How can I use a variable value as the name for another variable?
I want to make a custom event system in JavaScript:
  events: {
    registry: [],
    handlers: {},
    addHandler: function (event, handler) {
      if (this.registry.contains(event)) {
        this.handlers.insertVariableValueHere = handler;
      }
    },
  },

(it's a partial snippet)
But i want to  insert a variable value as part of the name of the variable in insertVariableNameHere part.
I also need to grab it from one of the function parameters (event).
How can I do this?
I tried different methods that i searched on Google and also here but none made sense.

this.handlers.insertVariableValueHere = handler; -> this.handlers[insertVariableValueHere] = handler;

"I also need to grab it from one of the function parameters (event)." How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?
